# How to get value from a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to run a function when my page id is true, which is working well and good, but I'm not able to get the values of the function.

What I wanted to achieve is I wanted to load the image URL from the calendar data, into the page which id is true for example if (page1) is true then I wanted to do a query search of image id in that page and load the image from the calendar data.

The  `getImageUrl(events[0].img);` gives me the image URL correctly but when I run this function inside the `if (page.id === "page1") {getImageUrl()}` the image URL is undefined. Is there a way or a different workaround for this? Is this possible to do? Please advise me. I'm quite new to the development.

```js
document.addEventListener("init", function (event) {
let page = event.target; 
     
     if (page.id === "page1") {

        // if page id is true this function will execute but im not able to get the image says undefined how do i get the function working right.
        getImageUrl();
 
} else if (page.id === "page2") {
          //do something
      }
});

//The below Queryselector id is avialble only for PAGE 1 where i want to run this function. 
function getImageUrl(url) {
  document.querySelector("#image-div").innerHTML += `<img src="${url}" />`;
}


//LOAD Calender and passing json ImageURLdata into the getImageUrl function
function loadCalender() {
  $("#container").simpleCalendar({
    onCalendarLoad : function (date, events) {
     getImageUrl(events[0].img);
     console.log(events[0].img);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not pass an image..... `getImageUrl();`<--- where is the image src?

Comment: The function is named `getImageUrl` - you mentioned "getting the image", yet the function "_SETS_" the HTML in the element. So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Is there a better way to getImageUrl() value inside the page.id if loop, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want. But I believe this is what you are trying.

```js
document.addEventListener("init", function (event) {
    let page = event.target; 

    var setImage = function (url) {
        var imgDiv = document.getElementById("image-div");
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = url;
        imgDiv.appendChild(img);
    }

    $("#container").simpleCalendar({
        onCalendarLoad : function (date, events) {
            if (page.id === 'page1') {
                setImage(events[0].img);
            } else if (page.id === 'page2') {
                // do something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mohamed, this is one way to look at it, still few bugs, im sure i can sort them. thank you so much

Comment: No problem :) 

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you try to do here.

1. the getImageUrl(url) function is more a setImageUrl... you are setting a value
2. the getImageUrl does not return any value so again something which does not make sense at all please provide a better code

Comment: Hello sorry, maybe the way i code is wrong, but what i wanted to do is I wanted to get the image URL from the onCalendarLoad : function (date, events) { } to the above if (page.id === "page1") {} how can i acheive this, do i have to store the function return value i a global varibale and will i be able to fetch from there.

Please help me.